# starred version of DeclareRobustCommand

Tags: macros, starred-version

I generally use `\newcommand*` instead `\newcommand` whenever it makes sense, to ease error checking if the command doesn't sensibly take multi-paragraph arguments.

Is there a starred version of `\DeclareRobustCommand` that does the same checking (that it, it makes sure that the arguments to the command are not multi-paragraph)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. It works the same way as in `\newcommand*`:

["4.10 Defining commands" in "LaTeX2e for class and package writers" (clsguide)](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/clsguide.pdf#nameddest=subsection.4.10)